# Reactive Redis: How to search using multiple indexes

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a spring boot application, and I am using reactive redis for data storage.
Now, I see there are multiple examples available on the internet for a String key. In my case, I have 3 fields that are indexed, and I would like to use 2 of them to search at a time.
How could I use 2 indexed fields to fetch data?

The following code is when I use a single string key:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, DummyData> redisTemplate;
private ReactiveValueOperations<String, DummyData> reactiveValueOps;

@PostConstruct
public void initService() {
    this.reactiveValueOps = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
}

@Override
public Mono<DummyData> getProductData(String number) {
    return this.reactiveValueOps.get(number);
}

@Override
public Mono<Boolean> createProductData(ProductData ProductData) {
    return this.reactiveValueOps.set(ProductData.getNumber(), DummyData);
}
```

I want a similar code but which uses multiple indexes for searching data.